# How to move the blockchain data while still being able to use the wallet?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

*Using the standard client, [Bitcoin-Qt](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin-Qt), v0.8.1:* (win10x64)

I would like to move the blockchain data from its default location to a different location (maybe even an external disk or [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) drive). What should I do to make this working while moving that data?

Comment: What operatng system?  Symlinks can help.

Comment: Asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*. Possible duplicate of *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This step-by-step how-to assumes you are using Windows 7 and installed Bitcoin-Qt to the default directory.

1. Make sure Bitcoin-Qt is not running
2. Create a desktop shortcut
3. Right click on the shortcut
4. Select *Properties*
5. In the "target" box, add `-datadir="the new data directory"`
6. Move everything in C:/Users/"your user name"/AppData/Roaming/Bitcoin/ to your new data directory.
7. Start Bitcoin-Qt with your new shortcut.

Comment: This moves the wallet too, which I think isn't what the asker wanted.

Comment: I do not want to move wallet file. Just chain, because it is growing too big you know.

Comment: Anybody know how to do this in linux ubuntu? Im going to run out of storage room before the blockchain synchronises. Its used 12 gig plus and still have 24 weeks to complete and I only have 2 gig left on my laptops hard drive and would like to store the blockchain on a removeable passport hard drive.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10551/how-do-i-specify-in-which-directory-bitcoin-blocks-and-other-data-should-be-stor

Answer (score 0):

Except for the most recent file (which is being written to with each new incoming block), I believe you shouldn't have a problem in moving the other files with the wallet still open - aren't they read only?

Moving the last one, though, would probably require you to close the wallet even if just temporarily.