# How do I specify in which directory Bitcoin blocks and other data should be stored?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf

I am on Windows and installed the Bitcoin wallet. The block folder seems to grow bigger everyday and is stored on my C drive in the roaming directory. I would like to set this to some other folder on another drive, which has more place. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*. Possible duplicate of *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you can specify this directory using the `datadir` configuration in `bitcoin.conf`.

```
-datadir=<dir>         Specify data directory
```

See [Running Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin).