# How do I relocate my bitcoin data in bitcoin-qt to save space?

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, bitcoin-qt-setup, storage-footprint

I am a rather new Bitcoin user, running bitcoin-qt on Linux.  However, due to limited disk space, the application is taking up too much of my drive.  I'm guessing this is due to the ever-expanding blockchain?  So, I was wondering if there is a way to relocate the data from bitcoin-qt to elsewhere.  I have another drive connected to my computer that I could put it on, but I do not know how to safely relocate it.  Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend reading about the [Bitcoin Data Directory](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory).  You should also take a look at this answer:  [How do I specify in which directory Bitcoin blocks and other data should be stored?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10551/how-do-i-specify-in-which-directory-bitcoin-blocks-and-other-data-should-be-stor)

Basically, all your Bitcoin data is stored in `~/.bitcoin` on Linux.  Not only can you specify a different location for this directory using `-datadir=/some/other/directory`, but you could also symlink `~/.bitcoin` to some other directory on a secondary disk or network share, like this:

`ln -s /some/other/directory ~/.bitcoin`

However, from personal experience, I would suggest not using a network share.