# How to uninstall Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I would like to know if you could help me, I downloaded the wallet of BITCOIN CORE and it occupied 25GB and filled my SSD i did not know that it takes more than 60GB, can you help me to uninstall the installed 25GB?

I would also like to install on my 1 TB hard drive, is it possible?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: related: [How can I run bitcoind in pruning mode?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37496/5406), [How to move the blockchain data while still being able to use the wallet?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/8985/5406)

Comment: Just for understanding: You don't really want to uninstall Bitcoin Core, you just want to move its directory, right?

Comment: I could not install it all because my ssd only had 25GB available, so it took up space, it already deletes the wallet but the 25GB is still occupied ... my operating system is windows 7